# Serie Fibonacci, solo llega a hasta la posición 47

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer el problema de la serie Fibonacci, el problema es que cuando llega un momento en el que al querer saber el valor del lugar 48, este es erróneo, aun cuando todos los demás están bien.

Éste es el código:

```
int main(){
    unsigned long int Anterior = 0,Actual = 1,Valor,Aux;
    printf("Ingresa el valor hasta el que llegara la serie.\n");
    scanf("%lu",&Valor);
    for(unsigned long int i=0; i<Valor; i++){
        if(i==0){
            printf("%lu.-\t0\n",i);
        }
        else{
            printf("%lu.- \t%lu\n",i,Actual);
            Aux = Actual;
            Actual = Actual + Anterior;
            Anterior = Aux;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El tipo unsigned long int tiene un límite en cuanto a que valor máximo pude almacenar y fib(48) es 4807526976.... Si quieres saber el número máximo que puedes almacenar en tu sistema con UL puedes hacer ésto: `#include<limits.h>;printf("%lu\n", ULONG_MAX);`. Siempre puedes pasar a unsigned long long...

Answer (score 1):

A pesar que su solucion es aceptable, la manera de implementar la serie de fibonacci es usando una tecnica llamada recursion.

Aca le dejo la solucion:

```
public static long fib(long n) {
      if ((n == 0) || (n == 1)){
          printf("%lu.-\t0\n",n);
          return n;
      }


      else {
         var result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
         printf("%lu.-\t0\n",result);
         return result
       }
   }

int main(){
   unsigned long Valor = 1;
   printf("Ingresa el valor hasta el que llegara la serie.\n");
   scanf("%lu",&Valor);

   long NumeroFinal = fib(Valor);
   return NumeroFinal;
}
```

Espero esta solucion le resuelva el problema, usar recursion incluye que su algoritmo tenga una complejidad O(n).

Comment: no comparto eso de que la solución deba ser por recursión. Dependerá de los requisitos, no crees? Además, no respondes a su pregunta

Comment: Gracias, por su comentario